# Можно ли обратится к элементу(элементам) через несколько указание нескольких атрибутов?

Tags: html, css, атрибуты, css-selectors

Возможно ли обратится к элементу(элементам) через указание нескольких атрибутов?

например: [class*="col"][role="main"] или [class*="col", role="main"] или [class*="col" role="main"]

Если возможно, то как корректно?

Comment: Через запятую не подойдёт?

Comment: Или что значит обратиться к нескольким атрибутам?

Comment: ...через запятую и пробел -- нельзя. попробовал -- [role="main"][class*="col"] -- прокатил в хроме.

Comment: наверно стоит обратится к стандарту **Selectors API Level 1** https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#interface-definitions

Comment: @Sublihim -- спасибо за ссылку. на mdn, htmlbook, wc3scool и webreferences -- не нашел инфы. --- w3.org -- читать -- ад.

Comment: о! --на русском есть: http://topolyan.com/w3c/selectors-api-ru.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Попробуйте так:

<div id="id_1" class="class_1">first</div>
<div id="id_2" class="class_2">second</div>
<div id="id_3" class="class_3">third</div>

<style>
  div[id=id_1][class=class_1], div[id=id_2][class=class_2] { color: red; }
  div[id=id_3][class=class_3] { color: blue; }
</style>
```

Документация доступна на русском по [ссылке](http://www.css-tricks.ru/articles/css/attribute-selectors).

Документация доступна английском по [ссылке](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector#attribute-selectors).

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Можно ссылку на документацию?

Comment: Нашел сам. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector#attribute-selectors

Comment: Это хорошо!)
Пожалуйста на русском! ссылка: http://www.css-tricks.ru/articles/css/attribute-selectors, на инглише:https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector#attribute-selectors

Comment: Предлагаю вам дополнить ответ. По ссылке полезная информация на русском. И то что нужно для ответа на вопрос там есть.

Comment: Принимаю Ваше предложение) Готово!